# Can i code C++ for non-os x based frameworks and such on Xcode?

Tags: c++

I have just begun learning C++ through a flemmish government funded course. I was given 'thinking in c++' by Bruce Eckel as my educative material.

Besides learning c++ i'm also picking up objective-c on my own as I go, my long-tearm goal is to be a independent osx/ios dev, but i have to learn an succeed in c++ for the funding to continue. Betting on two horses and such.. you're getting the picture, i'm sure.

So now it begins. I have to choose an IDE. Xcode seems only to serve the os x oriented C++ development as far as I understand... Am i right?

I would consider other IDE's like eclipse or even go linux and what not, but in the end, long term, I'm going to be coding in Xcode because of my independent ambitions... So it would be really convenient if I could get started with Xcode right away, nice and comfy, so i don't have to divide my 'learning curve' an lose valuable time

So the question nice and short; is it possible to code C++ for non-osx based sources and frameworks and what not. More importantly, can i learn everything in the book by Eckel if i stick to Xcode?

I'm a new kid on the block. Forgive stupid questions and wrong usage of dev lingo.

much obliged.

Comment: Yay for the Flemish government.  Your nick is the reason they cannot create one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - stick with Xcode - you don't need to use any Apple-specific frameworks - just build command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.  Most good programming language books don't talk much in terms of any particular editor or IDE.  And OS X is at least somewhat amenable to using open source software libraries that you might want over time (e.g. Boost).

Answer (score 0):

If have not used Xcode but I don't see why you should not be able to do so. If you want to build for non mac machines you just have to compile your code with the proper flags, and be mindful of the libraries available on the other system. As for frameworks, you won't find them on non mac machines so you shouldn't use -framework option in gcc.